# syntax highlighting not working in gedit

Tags: gedit

i download a asm-intel.lang file from here:
https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions

and i move it to the gtksourceview*.0/language-specs/

after i open gedit and change to Assembler(intel) in view->highlight mode

and the syntax highlighting not working, but if i chose c++ for example is working.

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use correct file-path:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/
cp asm-intel.lang ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
cp asm-intel.lang ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```

Comment: I used I tried to copy I tried to move and still it does not work